# java : Send Email from Server which is connected in LAN but Not in Internet

Tags: java, email

I am running my java web application in Jboss server 6.1, which is runnung on System '**A**'. Apache HTTPD server running on the System '**B**', which is acting as proxy server. 
System '**A**' is not exposed to Internet, but B is exposed to Internet. User can access the web application URL (A) through proxy(B).

**Problem** : My web application (A) generates email, which should be send to user. How to forward /send the email to end user, since A is not exposed to internet. Can we use Apache James to forward the mail.? If the system **A** is connected with internet, the application able to send mail. I am using Java Mail API.

Answer (score 0):

The javamail states that it cannot be used with a web proxy server, but offers an alternative with SOCKS. See link below:-

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#proxy

Comment: And yes you could probably use James mail server to forward these on from server B.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any other java open source mail server which can be configured easily?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any others, but I think there are a few available. Check out sourceforge.net for open source ones.